# Not able to invoke remote script in windows from linux using SSHEXEC

Tags: ant

I have set up OpenSSH in my windows environment and wants to invoke a ANT script from a Linux environment. But i'm getting the following error:

```
$ ant -f invoke.xml
Buildfile: /home/inysi/jpegu/cdt/tmp/invoke.xml
run:
  [sshexec] Connecting to ******
  [sshexec] cmd : ant -f build.xml
  [sshexec] uname: not found
  [sshexec] basename: not found
  [sshexec] dirname: not found
  [sshexec] Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  [sshexec]   We cannot execute java
  [sshexec] which: not found

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

But, i can invoke the remote ANT script in Linux environment using SSHEXEC from windows.

Can you please let me know, what could be the issue. JAVA_HOME is set in the windows environment variables. Where to set JAVA_HOME in the windows environment. Is there something similar to .bash_profile in windows. So that ANT process can pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are connecting to the user account that does not have its environment setup correctly, because it cannot find any standard commands.

Providing us with a better sample of invoke.xml may help.

Answer (score 0):

The invoke.xml file:
sshexec host="windows.host" username="Test" password="test123" trust="true"              command="ant -f build.xml

I have created the user "Test" in the windows host. I can invoke other commands e.g "java -version or java classname". But its only when i try to run an ANT script in the windows, it gives error "JAVA_HOME not defined".

It looks like the shell created at the SSH server side to invoke the command is not able to access the user environment variable "JAVA_HOME".